# Python Boost thinks two converters are duplicates, when their templated arguments are not

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to add these two converters to my python boost-library version.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::Device> cast_pointer_motor(std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::amarsi::MotorDriver> driver){
    return std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<sbcp::Device>(driver);
}

std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::Device> cast_pointer_power(std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::amarsi::Power> driver){
    return std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<sbcp::Device>(driver);
}

def("deviceMotorPtrCast",&cast_pointer_motor);
def("devicePowerPtrCast",&cast_pointer_power);
```

They are nearly identical, except that the template in the argument of the function is different.

However, upon loading this library in python, I get the exception:

```
test.py:1: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::Device> already registered; second conversion method ignored.
```

which leads to this further down

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::tr1::shared_ptr<sbcp::amarsi::Power>
```

So, how can I convince boost those two converters are actually different? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are not showing any to-Python convertors in this snippet, you are trying to define two Python method (using the same Pyrhon name for some reason).

Comment: Euhm, those 2 casters work as converters, no? And which methods have the same python name? (I'm confused now)

Comment: No sorry they are different names, I misread. But I still have no idea why they should act as  converters. You register a converter with `boost::python::to_python_converter`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) containing the module and how it is being invoked.  [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8da3db1c6530e828) is great for providing live examples too.  The casting functions being exposed are not registered as to-Python converters (implicitly through [`class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) or one of the explicit [to-Python converters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html#type_conversion)).